# Writing multiple lists to the same .dat file simultaniously in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-writing

This is my translation from pseudocode. The code suggests that multiple lists or arrays can be written to a .dat file. I'm trying to stay as true to the pseudocode format as I can so that I don't get lost in the Debugging process. For sake of space I have left out the actual Pseudocode. I know how to write everything into a .txt or .csv as string but is it possible to write them into the same file allowing each object to keep it's original value?(Num=Num and str=str)

```
#THIS IS THE PREMISE OF THE PSEUDOCODE
#Cooper College maintains a master file of students and credits
#earned. Each semester the master is updated with a transaction
#file that contains credits earned during the semester.
#Each file is sorted in Student ID number order.
```

THIS IS WHAT I'M ATTEMPTING TO TRANSLATE INTO PYTHON

```
#getReady()  
#   open master "studentFile.dat"
#   open trans "semesterCredits.dat"
#   open newMaster "updatedStudentFile.dat"
#   readMaster()
#   readTrans()
#   checkBoth()
#return
#
#readMaster()
#   input masterID, masterName, masterCredits from master
#   if eof then
#      masterID = HIGH_VALUE
#   endif
#return
```

THIS IS WHAT I WAS TRYING TO USE TO CREATE A STARTER FILE

```
#EACH LIST HAS A RANGE OF [0, 4]
masterID =[100000,100001,100002,100003]
masterName =['Bevis, Ted','Finch, Harold','Einstein, Al','Queen, Liz']
masterCredits = [56,15,112,37]

master = open('studentFile.dat','wb')
master.write(masterID,masterName,masterCredits)
print master.readlines()


#THIS IS MY TRACEBACK ERROR

#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "C:/Users/School/Desktop/Find the Bugs Ch7/debug07-03start.py",     
#line 6, in <module>
#master.write(masterID,masterName,masterCredits)
#TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
print master.readlines()
[[100001,'Bevis, Ted',56],[100002,'Finch, Harold',15],[100003,'Einstein, Al',112]...]
```

Comment: you have passed the list into your `write` function , Why your list have not the same length?can you show a sample format of an data that you want to write in your file?

Comment: let me edit for clarifacation

Comment: can you just show one line of expected output file? because there are many choice to write this data on file!

Comment: Basically it's a database for credits students have earned while attending school. Once a student ID is issued it will be attached to their name and this data will always remain the same. Each semester, they will earn more credits and the data will have to be adjusted in the master file. It also has to be searchable by ID# but I'm not there yet.

Comment: So why `masterID` and `masterName` and `masterCredits` has not the same length?does some of your master has not ID or some of them has the same?

Comment: `masterID` , `masterName` and `masterCredits` are the same length. `masterID[3]`, `masterName[3]`, and `masterCredits[3]` are respectively the last value in each list.

Comment: Yes, i seen your expected result checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desire lists with `zip` :

```
>>> zip(masterID,masterName,masterCredits)
[(100000, 'Bevis, Ted', 56), (100001, 'Finch, Harold', 15), (100002, 'Einstein, Al', 112), (100003, 'Queen, Liz', 37)]
```

Then all you need is looping over your zipped list and write to file :

```
with open('studentFile.dat','wb') as master:
    for i,j,k,z in zip(masterID,masterName,masterCredits) :
          master.write(','.join((str(i),j,k,str(z))))
```

Comment: @KirkStevenson oops sorry the last item needs to be convert to string! fixed

Comment: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found` is what I'm getting now

Comment: @KirkStevenson :D the firs item is int and need to convert i miss that!

Comment: I think we add an extra variable.

Comment: I got a traceback error pointing to an extra variable. If I remove j or k then it runs fine with the exception of no comma to separate the ID from the Credits. `masterName` is confusing because I used `(Last Name, First Name)` as one object.

Answer (score 0):

`write` takes a string, and you are passing a bunch of object. These need to be converted to string before printing. One way of doing this is

```
master.write(','.join([masterID,masterName,masterCredits]))
```

You make a list out of the items, join them with a comma and write to file.

Comment: I will try this. The file wasn't open for reading anyways. LOL. I tried doing a pickle import to write them but I couldn't read the data after I printed it.

Comment: I'm still getting the `TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)`. I really don't know enough about it, but my impression is I can only write one list to a file using this method.